# Using pytorch´s dataloader on an "mps" device won´t correctly load images

Tags: pytorch, conda, apple-m1, pytorch-dataloader

I´m trying out PyTorch's [DCGAN Tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html), using a Mac with an M1 chip.

For some reason, when loading images with the Dataloader, the resulting samples are corrupted when using: `device = torch.device("mps")`. But when using the `device = torch.device("cpu")` I get the correct result as shown below:

[image: the result is correct]

[I checked that MPS is correctly configured in my environment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSwFP.png) I'm using PyTorch's nightly build, which supports MPS acceleration on my MacOs version.

Is this a known issue?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this and can't test it myself without an M1, but mps support is relatively new to pytorch and I recommend dropping a question in the mps category of the pytorch forum so someone can look closer at this: https://discuss.pytorch.org/c/metal-performance-shader/